# Algorithm for parsing a "weighted" expression

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing

I'm on a big project, but I'm stuck at the first step.

Here is a simplification of my problem (In my real program, I don't store consonant, but objects with meta informations from *not-strong* words): 
    I have a "sentence" written using the following format :

- a *group* can be one *word* or three *group* (Yeah it's pretty
  recursive) separated by an x or a y.
- a *word* is a consonant followed by a vowel (except x and y).
- each *word* has a vowel that define his *deepness* (a:1, e:2, i:3... y's not in the list). Each *word* of a *group* has the same deepness

exemple : ba y ca x de x fe y ge
where (de x fe y ge) is the deepest group, and (ba x ca x (de x fe y ge)) is the principal group.

My algorithm has to split the string in a list of word (consonant+vowel). Then loop over the list to find the three deepest words. When it grabbed three words (a group) it transforms it into **one** word whose vowel is one time less deep than the original group deepness. And it loop again until it rest only one word.

exemple : ba x ca x de x fe y ge
list : [ba, ca, de, fe, ge]
the deepest vowel is 'e' so the algorithm get the three 'e'-tagged words : de, fe, ge and transforms it in one word with an e-1 deepness -> a. For the consonant, and here is my problem, it has to keep the consonant of the *strong word* of the group, it can be the first or the third (never the second) depending of if the group separator were x,y or y,x. in this case, it was x,y so the strong word will be the third (y indicate the strong word). The result is de 'x fe y ge' -> 'ga'.

What I'm not able to do is to get then keep the information of which word or group is strong after splitting into list.

I'm scripting with Python 3, but an answer in any langage is good (even in pseudo code, or just an explanation of how you would do it)

---

A few more exemples :
ba x ca y de y fi y gi x hi x je. Could be written (ba x ca y (de y (fi y gi x hi) x je))
step 1 : [ba, ca, de, fi, gi, he, je]
step 2 : fi, gi, hi (y, x)(don't know how to get these) **->** fe
We would have : ba x ca y de y fe x je
step 3 : de fe je (y, x again) **->** da
We would have : ba x ca y da 
step 4 : ba, ca, da (x, y this time) **->** ba (no vowel is less deep than a)

vi y go x jo y ko x bi x le y me y pa x qa (((vi y (go x jo y ko) x bi) x le y me) y pa x qa)
vi y ki x bi x le y me y pa x qa
ve x le y me y pa x qa
ma y pa x qa
ma

to finish :
be y ce x de y fa x ge y je x ke (be y ce x de) y fa x (ge y je x ke)
In this case, the program will loop twice on the 'e letter'
ba y fa x ge y je x ke
ba y fa x ga
ba
Think about it like a tournament in which every winner is already chosen.

Thanks for having read this, I hope you got it, and sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker (not a speaker at all in fact (-: )

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Show some code.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious deficiencies, and get it re-opened.

Comment: The lack of *any* code or design suggests that you need to study the basics of parsing and formal grammars.  Also, this structure would greatly help your description: you use many pronouns, some of which lack a clear reference to your unstated algorithm.  Clearing up half of them would let us finish editing the post for you.